# How to control and limit internet usage in a lan network?

Tags: internet, lan, proxy-server

Im working in an office which has so many computers who are connected to the internet via local network.
However,some users are using internet more than expected and cause low bandwidth to others.
I was thinking about running an active directory But some friends told me that i can run a proxy server on the manager computer and control the usage.
BUT,all the programs i found is working on LINUX only.
is there any way to control and limit the usage of users via an application in win XP ?

Comment: Via XP? I would try something else and ban all computers without security updates from internet connectivity. [This includes all computers with XP after the 8th of april 2014](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/lifecycle). Please get windows server, a win7/8 box. A linux box or whatever. But not XP.

Comment: There are several ways to shape your network traffic, partly depending on your infrastructure. Please extend your post with more details about your devices and network layout.

Answer (score 1):

The company I work for is the author of [WinGate](http://www.wingate.com), a web proxy (and other things) which runs on Windows from XP onwards. It also has a free edition.

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.

Comment: No problem. Your answer is OK but it would be much better if it was expanded a bit to explain how to limit internet usage for example.

Comment: This is a useful answer, Adrien. Ignore the power trip.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to squid for windows

http://sourceforge.net/projects/squidwindowsmsi/files/

Answer (score 0):

Manage Bandwidth on Your LAN With PRTG:: https://www.paessler.com/prtg
PRTG Network Monitor is the ideal solution for easy, reliable LAN bandwidth management. This bandwidth measurement software provides administrators with live readings as well as long-term usage trends, all in clear, easy-to-read graphs and tables.